# Multiple equal _ids and _revs returned from Cloudant query

Tags: cloudant

I use a dedicated IBM cloudant database:

When I'm retrieving values via Cloudant Query, sometimes I get multiple results with the same `_id` and `_rev`. 
I thought that `_id` and `_rev` are unique values.

I post the following

```
"selector": {
                    "$and": [
                        {
                            "v": {
                                "$eq": 1932
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "p": {
                                "$eq": "#204000102"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "t": {
                                "$lt": 1460980793,
                                "$gte": 1460980693
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "fields": [
                    "_id",
                    "_rev",
                    "v",
                    "p",
                    "t",
                    "m",
                    "w"
                ],
                "limit": 200
            }
```

To this URL: https://user_id-bluemix.cloudant.com/status/_find

When I look at the response, I see `_id` `8873c90f5dbd58c58e1a7d3b9d306d09` returned twice with the same `_id` and `_rev`.

Response:

```
 {
                "docs": [                      
                    {
                        "_id": "9d13cffbcba60d15eeb703d0f449004d",
                        "_rev": "2-41e4a578dda0e3a40cb244f13f07d842",
                        "v": "1932",
                        "p": "#204000102",
                        "t": 1460980698,
                        "m": 995,
                        "w": true
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "758ec066454846301bf2a8362fd815e4",
                        "_rev": "2-87c95fb7b043bb8d59740b9777e86bbe",
                        "v": "1932",
                        "p": "#204000102",
                        "t": 1460980764,
                        "m": 994,
                        "w": true
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "8873c90f5dbd58c58e1a7d3b9d306d09",
                        "_rev": "2-d979563cf6a6088dbdff64e95da14b96",
                        "v": "1932",
                        "p": "#204000102",
                        "t": 1460980693,
                        "m": 994,
                        "w": true
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "758ec066454846301bf2a8362fd815e4",
                        "_rev": "2-87c95fb7b043bb8d59740b9777e86bbe",
                        "v": "1932",
                        "p": "#204000102",
                        "t": 1460980764,
                        "m": 994,
                        "w": true
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "8873c90f5dbd58c58e1a7d3b9d306d09",
                        "_rev": "2-d979563cf6a6088dbdff64e95da14b96",
                        "v": "1932",
                        "p": "#204000102",
                        "t": 1460980693,
                        "m": 994,
                        "w": true
                    }
                ],
                "bookmark": "g1AAAAG1eJzLYWBgYMtgTmFQSklKzi9KdUhJMtMryE_WzcnPMzAw1EvOyS9NScwr0ctLLckBqmVKZEiS____f1YGk5uDcvh-BaBYEoNkVSiqGYZ4zUgC67KHGyN69wHYGJmDh0lxSpIDSFc83BhTNwawMRJFIiS5JgGkqx5uTOJ6iGukWu6R4po8FpDtB4AU0KT7EKNW_4W4SCyVgxQXQYx6ADEK6qpIwwZIUO9_lAUAiVOIPw"
            }
```

Could anybody explain to me, why Cloudant sends multiple results with the same `_id` and `_rev`?

Comment: Can you share your indexes? I don't have a grand theory here. It just may help me understand your query a bit more. Also,  is "v" a numeric field, or a string field? You are querying it as a numeric, but looks like it's returned as a string. Again, I don't think that's related; just want more info about the query.

Comment: These are my indexes:

{
indexes: [
{
ddoc: null,
name: "_all_docs",
type: "special",
def: {
fields: [
{
_id: "asc"
}
]
}
},
{
ddoc: "_design/vision_index",
name: "vision_index",
type: "text",
def: {
default_analyzer: "keyword",
default_field: {
enabled: false
},
selector: { },
fields: [
{
v: "number"
},
{
p: "string"
},
{
t: "number"
},
{
w: "boolean"
}
],
index_array_lengths: true
}
}
]
}

Comment: This is a example document:
 {
                            "_id": "8873c90f5dbd58c58e1a7d3b9d306d09",
                            "_rev": "2-d979563cf6a6088dbdff64e95da14b96",
                            "v": 1932,
                            "p": "#204000102",
                            "t": 1460980693,
                            "m": 994,
                            "w": true
                        },

Comment: Having a difficult time reproducing. Are you experiencing the same issue when running the query in the Cloudant dashboard?